# Angular2 auto convert JSON response to class

Tags: angular, class, typescript

I have this clases:

```
import { Address } from './address';
import { Contact } from './contact';

export class User {
  public $class = 'org.test.crm.participants.User';

  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public surname: string,
    public jobTitle: string,
    public address: Address,
    public contacts: Contact[]
  ) {}
}

export class Address {

  public $class = 'org.test.crm.concepts.Address';
  public street: string;
  public city: string;
  public state: string;
  public country: string;
  public postCode: string;
  public timeZone: string;

  constructor(
    address: Address
  ) {
    this.street = address.street;
    this.city = address.city;
    this.state = address.state;
    this.country = address.country;
    this.postCode = address.postCode;
    this.timeZone = address.timeZone;
  }
}

export class Contact {

  public $class = 'org.test.crm.concepts.Contact';
  public email: string;
  public telephone: string;
  public mobile: string;

  constructor(contact: Contact) {
    this.email = contact.email;
    this.telephone = contact.telephone;
    this.mobile = contact.mobile;
  }
}
```

I have service, where after call it returns JSON like:

```
[  
   {  
      "$class":"org.test.crm.participants.User",
      "id":"USER_1",
      "name":"Vin",
      "surname":"Diesel",
      "jobTitle":"CEO",
      "address":{  
         "$class":"org.test.crm.concepts.Place",
         "street":"Some street",
         "city":"Some city",
         "postCode":"100 00",
         "state":"",
         "country":"CZE",
         "timeZone":"UTC"
      },
      "contacts":[  
         {  
            "$class":"org.test.crm.concepts.Contact",
            "email":"vin@diesel.com"
         }
      ],
      "systemInformation":{  
         "$class":"org.test.crm.concepts.SystemInformation",
         "created":"2018-03-14T11:53:52.773Z",
         "createdBy":"resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin",
         "lastModified":"2018-03-14T11:53:52.773Z",
         "lastModifiedBy":"resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin"
      }
   }
]
```

Is there any simple way how to convert this result to array of Users? How I can change my constructors or other stuffs to auto convert return of ajax? For now i´m doing this:

```
this.users = <User[]> result;
```

But that dont convert result to User class, returns is just JSON array as before ... When I do manual assign all attributes, its correct User class ... Can I do that automatically?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the server already returns result in the expected format. Right? So the conversion `<User[]>` should be enough... Or I am mising something

Comment: when I do <User[]>, in return I doesnt have any Users, its just arrays of JSON

Comment: as you have array of users

Comment: Can you show your service method?

Comment: The objects returned from server already have all the properties, you need. So at least from the "duck typing" point of view, it should be fine. If you want instances of that class User, then you will have to call constructor manually

Comment: You can use a deserializer like https://kaiu-lab.github.io/serializer/

Answer (score 0):

You can map the array and make use of *Object.assign*

```
this.users = result.map( user => Object.assign(new User(), user));
```

Comment: this convert result to user, what is correct :) But in contact array and address are still as json (not correct objects)

Comment: you can use JSON.parse() to convert the JSON result to an Object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

The `this.users = <User[]> result;` is equal to just `this.users = result;`. The `<User[]>` annotation just tells TypeScript compiler what `result` should be in compile time, and it doesn't add any checks or transformations to the runtime.

> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

The problem you face is de-serialisation problem.
As your initial data is a JSON string, you could use `reviver` function when calling `JSON.parse(string, reviver)` in your service.
http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
const getReviver = (classes: any[]) => {
  const classMap = classes.reduce((map, class) => {
    if(class.$class){
      map[class.$class] = class;
    }
    return map;
  }, {});

  const reviver = (key, value) => {
    if(typeof value === 'object' && value.$class && classMap[value.$class]) {
      return new classMap[value.$class](value);
    }
    return value;
  }

  return reviver;
}
```

example

```
const reviver = getReviver([Address, Contact])
const revivedData = JSON.parse(string, reviver);
```